# R. Add column to df where rows have names of element from list

Tags: r, list

I have a list of all files (dataframes) within a directory:

```
library("plyr")
library("dplyr")
library("broom") 
library("tidyr")

snp_list <- list.files(pattern="*.txt", all.files = T,full.names = F)
```

I also have a dataframe A obtained through the following function:

```
pv1= lapply(snp_list, function(x) tidy(lm(PV ~ GT*SEX + M + GT*N,read.table(x,header=TRUE)))) %>%  
bind_rows()
```

Dataframe A has 7 rows ((Intercept), GT, SEX, M, N, GT:SEX, GT:N) for each element in list snp_list. In this toy example the list has 3 elements (rs1406947.txt  rs25904.txt  rs7133579.txt), but in reality there are 1,200,000 elements

A:

```
term    estimate    st.error    statistic    p.value
(Intercept)    7.68    0.17    44.64    0
GT    0.01    0.01    0.07    0.19    
SEX    1.52    0.14    10.87    0.1 
M    0.12    0.29    0.41    0.67   
N    -0.06    0.12    -0.48    0.63
GT:SEX    -0.03    0.08    -0.44    0.65
GT:N    -0.00    0.06    -0.08    0.93   
(Intercept)    9.23    0.20    34.64    0
GT    0.05    0.04    0.12    0.22    
SEX    1.67    0.76    10.34    0.1 
M    0.14    0.39    0.51    0.55   
N    -0.08    0.05    -0.46    0.55
GT:SEX    -0.19    0.11    -0.34    0.44
GT:N    -0.22    0.33    -0.44    0.55           
(Intercept)    7.99    0.66    44.44    0
GT    0.01    0.3    0.04    0.33    
SEX    1.22    0.22    10.44    0.15 
M    0.88    0.22    0.33    0.44   
N    -0.5    0.5    -0.5    0.6
GT:SEX    -0.06    0.09    -0.74    0.35
GT:N    -0.00    0.03    -0.04    0.78
```

I want to add a new column "SNP" to A, where each row has the name of the element the rows belongs to (nrows = 7*1,200,000). I would get this:

```
term    estimate    st.error    statistic    p.value    SNP
(Intercept)    7.68    0.17    44.64    0    rs1406947
GT    0.01    0.01    0.07    0.19    rs1406947     
SEX    1.52    0.14    10.87    0.1    rs1406947 
M    0.12    0.29    0.41    0.67    rs1406947   
N    -0.06    0.12    -0.48    0.63    rs1406947
GT:SEX    -0.03    0.08    -0.44    0.65    rs1406947
GT:N    -0.00    0.06    -0.08    0.93    rs1406947   
(Intercept)    9.23    0.20    34.64    0    rs25904
GT    0.05    0.04    0.12    0.22    rs25904    
SEX    1.67    0.76    10.34    0.1    rs25904 
M    0.14    0.39    0.51    0.55    rs25904   
N    -0.08    0.05    -0.46    0.55    rs25904
GT:SEX    -0.19    0.11    -0.34    0.44    rs25904
GT:N    -0.22    0.33    -0.44    0.55    rs25904           
(Intercept)    7.99    0.66    44.44    0    rs7133579
GT    0.01    0.3    0.04    0.33    rs7133579    
SEX    1.22    0.22    10.44    0.15    rs7133579 
M    0.88    0.22    0.33    0.44    rs7133579   
N    -0.5    0.5    -0.5    0.6    rs7133579
GT:SEX    -0.06    0.09    -0.74    0.35    rs7133579
GT:N    -0.00    0.03    -0.04    0.78    rs7133579
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do what you asked:

```
A$SNP=rep(0,nrow(A))
for (i in 1:nrow(A)){
  A$SNP[i]=snp_list[(i%/%8)+1]
}
```

Using integer division, you can generate an index for 7 elements to map to each element in snp_list.

Comment: @Lucas I reread your question and understand it better now. I am not sure there is a very idiomatic way to do it, but here's a for loop that accomplishes what you want.

Comment: Thanks @jfahne !. You almost got the right answer. The only problem is that I get rs1406947.txt for the first 6 rows, then rs25904.txt for the next 7, then rs7133579.txt for the next 7 and so on. I should get rs1406947 for the first 7 rows, rs25904 for the next 7 and rs7133579 for the next 7.

Comment: @Lucas I corrected my code. The issue was the `1:nrow(A)` should have been `0:nrow(A)`. This should get you all seven elements.

Comment: Thanks @jfahne !. Unfortunately, I still get the same 6-7-7 (the very last row has NA) elements instead of 7-7-7

Comment: @Lucas I edited that mindlessly. It should work now because `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...` should now map to `1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,...`.

Comment: Hi @jfahne, I am sorry for bothering you again. I just realized that I keep getting the same 6-7-7 pattern. Do you have any suggestion? Many thanks